# Covert JSON from One Format to Other Format?

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON

```
                "ID": "234AS",
                "Name": "SynchronousMate",
                "Type": "Node",
                "SubType": "SubNode",
                "Dynamic": "Yes",
                "DisplayName": "Sync",
                "Direct": "Yes",
                "Category": "IT",
                "Properties": {
                    "Property": [
                        {
                            "Name": "A",
                            "Value": "Anant"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "B",
                            "Value": "Bharat"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "C",
                            "Value": "Cynus"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "D",
                            "Value": "Dynana"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "E",
                            "Value": "Elegant"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Bank",
                            "Value": "BOB"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "ipAddress",
                            "Value": "101.90.34.12"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "siteName",
                            "Value": "BRS-WDM-PSS-X7A6"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Longitude",
                            "Value": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "FullName",
                            "Value": "network:10.254.0.46"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "NumberOfShelves",
                            "Value": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "GEOCODE.Latitude",
                            "Value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Properties": ""
            }
..............................
..............................
```

How to convert this JSON to like this

```
{

            "ID": "234AS",
            "Name": "SynchronousMate",
            "Type": "Node",
            "SubType": "SubNode",
            "Dynamic": "Yes",
            "DisplayName": "Sync",
            "Direct": "Yes",
            "Category": "IT",
            "A" : "Anant",
            "B" : "Bharat",
            "C" : "Cynus",
            "D" : "Dynana",
            "E" : "Elegant",
            "Bank" : "BOB",
            "ipAddress" :  "101.90.34.12",
            "siteName" : "BRS-WDM-PSS-X7A6",
            "Longitude" : ""0",
            "FullName" : "network:10.254.0.46",
            "NumberOfShelves" : 0,
            "GEOCODE.Latitude" : 0




        },
............................
............................
```

Comment: can you describe in words what is actual change, while comparing we might miss few things.

Comment: @Mritunjay In First JSON WHat all the Property now its Part of JSOn as a Key/value Pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `properties` and create a `Map` with key the value of `Name` and as value the value of `Value`.

Comment: This is one elements only i showed here like this may be Hundreds of elements possible So Map will not be Heavy in-terms of memory ?

Comment: A Map is not so heavy and it is very flexible. If you need to add or remove properties the Map is the right choice. Instead if the number and name of properties is predefined you can build a class with your needs without using a Map

Comment: CLass will be two varaible Key/Value now from this List of class how to add values other half of JSON?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi the other properties are normal String properties with getter and setter having same name of the properties in the json

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, Get/Store the Property JsonArray. Then iterate it putting the 
elements of array in Map. And then add the map to the other half of JSON.

Comment: Upto Map its Fine how to add in other Half can you add code SnapShot

Comment: I cannot write code for you. i am giving the idea, how it can be achieved.
As it is already a Json object, check after every element, if there is another json object/array, if it is, create a Map and add the elements to it.
Once the inner json object is reach to its end, add its elements to outer map, and continue
@SubodhJoshi